# Use laravel Auth::check() in API FormRequest

Tags: laravel

I made an API to my application and then starting using it even inside the application. That is, my blade views for display, edit etc sends ajax requests to routes configured in routes/api.php. Now I would need to do Auth::check() inside an API routes form request but found it is not available under the "api" middleware. Any way to salvage my situation? What is the easiest way to look for logged in users in API?

EDIT:
this is what I tried to do in the api form request.

```
public function authorize()
{
    $slot = Slot::find($this->route('slot'));
    // If administrator is logged in all is good.
    // If slot is free its also ok.
    return ( Auth::check() || $slot->isAvailable() );
}
```

Comment: `Auth::check()` should be available everywhere, do you get any error?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`auth` middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes).

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    // Only authenticated users allowed here

});
```

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear, unauthenticated users should also be allowed (as long as that Slot is free) See updated question. Thank you!